Is it possible to send the DOM object to the server as a request?
I need to send an DOM Object to the server in HTTP request. Is it possible ?
Use case : I have a reports tab, where the data are not stored in DB. Those are hard coded probably in a properties file lets say. With those data I have generated the report (using hbs). Now I need to convert that report into a pdf. So what I thought is, If I send the data from the client to server in DOM object it would be easy for me to construct the PDF in the backend.
Is it possible? If so how it can be implemented ? or Is there any other feasible method to solve this?
Thanks in advance!!!
